# How can I filter a random Haskell list so that each element is no more than distance n apart from the next?

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm writing a program in Haskell that generates random triads of ints in order to play them as chords using Euterpea. Here's what my list of lists looks like (obviously, it's infinite, but I'll `take 10 $ chop 3 $ randInts`, where chop is just a function that splits a list up into (ordered) groupings of three and randPitch simply generates ints over the interval 24 - 84):

```
[[27,33,48],[53,59,82],[31,49,62],[50,60,63],[51,56,79],[57,59,60],[52,63,69],[52,77,79],[32,32,37],[39,77,84]]
```

To learn a bit about music theory, I'm applying various filters to these triads. The one that's giving me trouble (at least to implement in Haskell, which is a new language for me) is what Dmitri Tymoczko would call "conjunct melodic notation"--i.e., melodies (in this case the top 'note' or pitch of the 3-tuple) should only move short distances.

**What I want to do is write a function that recursively filters the endless list of triads such that what results is a list of triads whose top note only moves by <= *n* between each chord**: essentially, a kind of random walk where you are only allowed to move *n* semitones for any one step. Here are the functions I have so far:

```
jumpSize :: (Num a, Ord a) => [[a]] -> [[a]]
jumpSize (_:[]) = []
jumpSize (x:y:[]) = (abs (maximum x - maximum y) : x) : []
jumpSize (x:y:zs) = (abs (maximum x - maximum y) : x) : jumpSize (y:zs)
```

This will prepend the distance from triad x to y at the beginning of list x. So `take 5 $ jumpSize $ chop 3 $ randPitch` gives me:

```
[[34,27,33,48],[20,53,59,82],[1,31,49,62],[16,50,60,63],[19,51,56,79]]
```

I tried to write a recursive function that filters out all the chords with jumps of great than *n*, recalculates the new jumpSizes and then applies itself again. However, I'm having trouble because this function is either crashing GHCi or giving me all sorts of problems. Structurally, I would like to still produce the chords by filtering over the random array, but I think I'm missing something about how to best do this in a functional language. Maybe I need to supply an initial generator chord? Thanks!

```
jumpRecur :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
jumpRecur n (xs)
    | [x | x <- xs, head x > n] == []   = xs
    | otherwise                 = jumpRecur n $ jumpSize $ filter (\x -> head x <= n) xs
```

Here's a sample output:

```
*Main> jumpRecur 5 $ jumpSize $ chop 3 $ take 1000 $ randPitch
[[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,70,70,76],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,55,74,74],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,26,28,73],         [3,3,3,3,3,3,0,1,26,69,74],[5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,33,43,77],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,47,67,82],[2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,37,66,82],[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,59,69,84],[4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,59,79,81],[4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,28,69,77],[5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,54,68,73],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,32,73,78],[5,5,5,5,5,5,1,4,52,62,78],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,58,71,73],[3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,25,64,73],[1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,35,42,76],[4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,35,39,77]]
```

Comment: Why not just generate random numbers within that range?  At each iteration you could generate a random number `randomR (-n, n) gen` and add it to the previous top note.

Comment: I mean that's exactly how I would do it in an imperative language. I guess I liked the challenge of imagining all the possible chords in some giant infinite array and then having to filter them down.

Comment: If you can do it in an imperative language, why not in Haskell?  There are some caveats to dealing with random number generation, though.  I would recommend using the `Rand` monad from the [MonadRandom](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom) package.  I'll post an example of how to use it.

Comment: If you want to carefully preserve the exact distribution of your random chords, rejection might be the way to go.  In your case, it isn't clear why you might prefer one distribution to another -- but you might want to try both, to see how they sound...

Comment: @todkwxrtvwmzonunswam [Here's](https://gist.github.com/bheklilr/6c16c338063644a208c8) an example that seems to work pretty well.  Like comingstorm says, you'll want to test it out and modify it to suit your tastes.  The random number generation is a little tricky because you have to calculate a new range for each note in the chord, but I added lots of comments to help out.  If you have any questions, just ask.  Hopefully this will help you out

Comment: @bheklilr that's amazing--thanks! I haven't yet used monads (this is my first little foray into Haskell) so your code and comments are very helpful.

Comment: @todkwxrtvwmzonunswam Monads can be tricky things.  It'll take a while until they "click", but once they do, you'll realize just how powerful of an abstraction they can be.  What's going on with the `Rand StdGen` monad is nothing more than wrapping up the `State StdGen` monad and adding some convenience functions for getting random values.  There's some complicated plumbing, but essentially it's just managing that annoying random generator you normally have to pass around when dealing with random values.

Comment: The `State` monad is deceptively simple, and all it does is keep up with a value that changes over time.  With random number generation, this value is your seed (or generator).  Because you want the seed to change after each use (otherwise you wouldn't get random values), you either have to deal with `IO` or manage the "state" that is a changing seed.  The `Rand` monad just has this behavior implemented for you and makes it easy to get random numbers.  If any of this doesn't make sense yet, don't worry, it's confusing to just about everyone at first.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably good Haskell idiom to generalize the filter, as follows:

```
jumpBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]

jumpBy ok (x:y:zs) | ok x y    = x:jumpBy ok (y:zs)  -- accept y & step
                   | otherwise = jumpBy ok (x:zs)    -- reject y & retry
jumpBy _ xs = xs
```

If you are sure all input will be infinite lists, you don't really need that last line which handles the ends of finite lists, but it's good practice to handle all cases.

Then, use your general filter with your specific test:

```
jumpSize = jumpBy (\x y -> abs(maximum x - maximum y) < n)
```